# MySQL join statement syntax issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I am trying to update 2 columns in 1 table using 3 tables data(join) Some how its throwing syntax error. when I execute with 1 "SET" out of  2 "SET" statements its working fine. But if I use 2 SET statements its giving syntax error.(Line 6 and 7) Could some one please correct my statement

```
UPDATE TIBENVINFO tei  
            INNER JOIN TIB_CROSSREF tcr 
                  ON (tei.ProductName = tcr.Env_Product_Name and tei.Version = tcr.Version ) 
            INNER JOIN ENDOFSUPPORTPRODUCTINFO esi 
                  ON (esi.ProductName = tcr.Support_Product_Name)            
             **SET tei.SupportEndDate = esi.EndOfSupportDate,
             SET tei.UpdateRequired = 'Yes'**
            Where (DATEDIFF(esi.EndOfSupportDate,CURDATE()) < 90) and tei.HostName = "XXXXXXXXX"
```

Error :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET tei.UpdateRequired = 'Yes'
Where (DATEDIFF(esi.EndOfSupportDate,CURDAT' at line 7

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. Chop down code to minimal. Google the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `set` once, with the columns separated by commas:

```
SET tei.SupportEndDate = esi.EndOfSupportDate, 
    tei.UpdateRequired = 'Yes'
```

I would also recommend rewriting the date comparison to be:

```
where esi.EndOfSupportDate > curdate() - interval 90 day and
      tei.HostName = 'XXXXXXXXX'  -- note single quotes not double quotes
```

Not only is this easier to write and read, but it is also easier to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write SET keyword again and again in an UPDATE query. Its syntax is:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column_name = value
```

So, if you want to update multiple columns in a table you can add commas within the column names like this:

```
SET tei.SupportEndDate = esi.EndOfSupportDate, tei.UpdateRequired = 'Yes'
```

Hope it will work for you..